# focus the textbox after jquery ui dialog is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have a textbox on my asp.net MVC view which shows a JQuery UIi dialog on focus. On this dialog, I want to make sure that when OK button is clicked, the same textbox on parent page should get focus which showed popup. I tried to use JQuery focus after and before close like this:

```
$(this).dialog("close");
$("#DefaultCallFrom1").focus();
```

but It is not working. Please suggest a solution to this.

Answer (score 2):

When initializing the dialog, use the close event to set the focus when the dialog is closed :

```
$(this).dialog({
  close: function( event, ui ) {
     $("#DefaultCallFrom1").focus();
  }
});
```

jQuery UI Dialog [**Docs**](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-close) for the close event.

**EDIT**

If you're trying to apply focus after a button in the dialog is clicked, that should be as simple as :

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({ 
    autoOpen: true,
    buttons: [ 
        { 
            text: "Ok", click: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" ); 
                $('#DefaultCallFrom1').focus();
            } 
        } 
    ] 
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/q9L86/)

Comment: I need to do it on OK button after performing some functionality on OK click

Comment: also, I added above close function code to my dialog and it added a new button named close and clicking it is not closing the dialog .. I think because popup reappears because of this focus call.

Comment: thanks but what about if autoOpen is false and #dialog is opened on click of $('#DefaultCallFrom1') ? In that case dialog will not close because of loop ...

Comment: What loop?? Are you opening the popup when focusing the input and the trying to focus the input again when the dialog closes? If so use one().

Comment: You can't use an event handler that opens a dialog on every focus, that would create a loop, one() is like on(), but it fires only once.